# Screenshot of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas box and I need to take a screenshot of it to save onto the same page under the canvas box. When you click on the small picture it should bring you to a bigger picture. I want it to take as many screen shots as I want and have them all show up on the page until I press clear.

I know that I could use the dataToUrl() for the saving part, but I don't know how the go about the rest of it.

Comment: so.. what have you tried?

Comment: Have you seen [toDataUrl()](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/)?

Comment: function copy() {
        var imgData=ctx.getImageData(650,500);
        ctx.putImageData(imgData,650,500);
      }                                      I have tried this because I found it somewhere but it doesn't work.. I think I need to be able to press a button like save and then it takes the screen shot

Comment: and yah i have read some bit about the toDataUrl() but i am not sure how exactly does it work

Comment: Spend a bit learning about toDataURL.  It creates a dataURL of your canvas (used, for example, as the .src to an img element)  toDataURL is what you need :)

Comment: So the toDataURL is the only option ? :)

Comment: It's certainly the easiest.  You can get all the pixels on the canvas with getImageData and then assemble your own bitmap--but I wouldn't do it that way!  ;-)

Comment: would yu know anything about it? because i have this written down        function to_image(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById("container");
                document.getElementById("container").src = canvas.toDataURL();
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(box);
            }     And its not doing anything. I have an example of a different one and code is basically the same. So i don't know what im doing wrong :( :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
//define some HTML to play with
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<p><button type="button" id="savebutton">Save canvas</button></p>
<div id="gallery"></div>

<script>
//capture HTML elements
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var saveButton = document.getElementById('savebutton');
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

//draw something in canvas to be captured
ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.font = '50px Arial, sans-serif';
ctx.textAlign = 'center';
ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
ctx.fillText('Hello, world', 200, 100);

//define an event listener for the button
var addImage = function(e){
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    gallery.appendChild(img);
    if(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;
    }
};
//clicking the button will create an image element from the canvas data
//and append it as a child element to the gallery div
saveButton.addEventListener('click', addImage, false);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KaliedaRik/77bNp/

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for :) Do you maybe know how I can put the copied image into a div box and make it smaller than the original one too?

Comment: Either CSS style any images added to the gallery div -- #gallery img { width: 20%; } -- or, alternatively, set the width style when generating the image -- img.src = canvas.toDataUrl(); img.style.width = '20%';

Comment: Thanks there is something still not working tho :/ Its driving me crazy ha